# sed from terminal when replacing double quotes with single quotes

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have

```
echo "A url: \\\"http:..."
```

which reads `"A url: \"http:..."` (<- this is how it is in my text file)

I need

```
echo "A url: \'http:..."
```

however because of all the quotes my sed command does not work properly

```
echo "A url: \\\"http:..." | sed -r 's/\\"+/\\\'/g'
```

I can see why it fails (the single quote in the middle of the sed statement is the problem, but what can I do about it? I tried looking for a third type of quotes to use, but could not find one. Any hacks?

Comment: Why is `sed` needed? What do you start from? Is this in a file or are you `echo`ing the string directly? Would `echo "A url: \'http:..."` be enough? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change any occurrence of `\"` with `\'`, you can do this:

```
$ echo "A url: \\\"http:..." | sed -r "s/\\\"/\\'/g"
A url: \'http:...
```

Just use `"` for the outer quotes in your `sed` and you can then use `'` in the replacement. You don't want `"+` unless you might have more than one consecutive `"` and you want to replace all of them. If you do, use `sed -r "s/\\\"+/\\'/g"`.